# how to make a trigger from a php page

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

suppose i have a databse exam(id,ststus) now, status is not started,but i want to change status to 'started' after a particular time.
Now i know, i can write a trigger for this,to change it ,depending on sysdate.

but,as i am making a website in php,so i have to write the code in a php page.

my question is, 
1) will the trigger work automatically,or i need to at least open that particular page,leave it as it is, then at particular time,it will get refreshed and database will change?

2)how exactly does this trigger work?

Comment: Did you read about triggers in the manual before opening this question?

Comment: read about cron, it fits better for your need

Answer (score 0):

Trigger can be run ON DELETE, ON UPDATE or ON INSERT a row in table, and it is stored in db and you don't have to call any page to run it.
Events çan be schedule and it can be run after a period, for example every one week, i think you need an event.